# sage -i -> sage-run received unknown option: -i

Tags: ubuntu, sage

I'm trying to install a sage package (namely plantri) using sage -i plantri. I receive the message: sage-run received unknown option: -i.

I have opened a sage shell via sage -sh and repeated the same command (sage -i plantri). Received the same message. I am using SageMath version 8.1, Release Date: 2017-12-07.

I have tried using the sage installation via the ubuntu package repositories and with a manual installation (download and compile sage myself). How can I install additional packages in sage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sage -i` command only works with a Sage you compiled from source.

If you have installed Sage from the Ubuntu package repository,
and also compiled it from source, the `sage` in your path is
probably the one from the Ubuntu package repository.

To install `plantri` for the Sage you compiled from source,
either use its full path or navigate to its location and
use `./sage`. If your Sage installation is in `~/SageMath`
these two solutions would look like:

either

```
~/SageMath/sage -i plantri  # tell that Sage to install plantri
```

or

```
cd ~/SageMath  # assuming this is where Sage is installed
./sage -i plantri  # tell this Sage here to install plantri
```

Comment: My use case is distro-installed sage. How do I install sage packages then? I _want_ the repository version of sage, and I _also_ want to be able to install packages into it. How do I?

Comment: It depends what package. Install with your distro's package manager those that are packaged there, with pip those that are pip-installable. Otherwise, which package(s) specifically is this about? Sometimes the solution is to package them yourself. For instance, someone [asked about installing the Stein-Watkins database on Arch Linux](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/62750) and then [packaged it themself on AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/sage-data-stein-watkins).